# Xcode 4.4.1 Confuses Itself (I think)

Tags: xcode

Wow, this is frustrating.

Recently upgraded to OS X 10.8 and Xcode 4.4.1  I was working along just fine when Xcode seemed to lose track of symbols and methods.  It started to think that a wide variety of things were not defined, declared, synthesized etc when in fact they are just fine (the project built just fine and in some cases the symbols are right there in the file).  Also, the number of issues jumps around.  Generally it finds 4 issues in one file (the AppDelegate) but if you look at any of those errors it quickly ups the issues to 13 or 14.  These newer issues seem mostly of the type you get when you don't import the header files but that's never been a problem before.

Looking around in SO I see that sometimes people clear out the DerivedData folder or other various tricks.  I made a DerivedData2 folder and pointed to it, but that didn't fix the problem.

I am using git but have not been committing often to retreat to a desirable point (work would be lost/yes, lesson learned).  I also read on SO that sometimes it is git file that gets confused.

Sorry this is so general.  Are there any suggestions about what/how to reset to unconfuse Xcode?  I hope this is not a feature of Xcode 4.4.1! I won't rule out that it's something I did... but I thought it was worth asking about Xcode problems and how people have dealt with them.

**EDIT:**  @Abizem 's trick helped a lot.  Now I have really only one problem left, so I can get down to details.  Remember, this code was working fine and just stopped.  In AppDelegate I have for the .h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> 
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tbc;
@end
```

then in .m

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tbc = _tbc;
```

It's almost as if there is a typo, but I don't think so.  The error I get is `Property implementation must have its declaration in interface 'AppDelegate'` pointing at the `@synthesize tbc` line.  It doesn't get any more basic than this.  Why doesn't Xcode recognize this?

**EDIT 2:**  With the `@synthesize` for `window` and `tbc` commented out, the following lines all complain about `property tbc not found on object type AppDelegate *`.  By the way, these issues were present before I commented stuff out, I thought they were related to the complaint about `property declaration... interface` and would go away when that was fixed, but apparently not.  Xcode simply doesn't know where/what `tbc` is any longer.  No override of any methods for these objects.  I must have a poltergeist!

```
self.tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];       
self.tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:gameVC, settingsVC, helpVC, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tbc;
```

Comment: A clean build generally fixes it.

Comment: @Abizern I should have mentioned I clean the project regularly.  In this case it changes nothing.  Is there a way to clean beyond Product -> Clean?  Thank you.

Comment: try holding down the alt key, it goes further and deletes the build folder.

Comment: @Abizem Thank you for this tip.  I had read that one could delete the folder but couldn't find how.  So this is great to know.  Now, taking this action did seem to clean up about 90% of the problems, the 4 issues remain.  These are really the same issue, it isn't recognizing a property declaration which is clearly there.  I'll have to dig into this and report back later.

Comment: @Abizem Edited question with more details of the remaining problem.

Comment: If you're using LLVM4 as the compiler, you don't need the two @synthesize lines. Delete them and see if you still have the problem (it could be something else in your file and this will help to show it up)

Comment: Commented them out.  Any line below which uses `tbc` claims `property not found` while the `window` uses come through fine.  Seems to be something unique to `tbc`.  Previously I searched the whole project for this string and this is the only place it is used.

Comment: Without seeing the file and the project - there's nothing else I can suggest.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll be pondering it.  Weird.

Comment: @Bryan If you deleted the @ synthesize lines and got the property not found error, I think means you are overriding the setters, right? Care to paste that?

Comment: @Mazyod Added EDIT 2 to original question.  No overriding is the short answer.  Thank you for looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Abizem @Mazyod Found the problem.  I had most of my `#import` statements in a pch.  Apparently the new Xcode gets grumpy about this practice.  I moved them to the appropriate files and it worked again.  The only things left in my pch are Apple items.  I also deleted my Snapshots and DerivedData folders, and cleaned a whole bunch.  I'm not sure deleting the folders was really part of the fix.